# How to use updateMany with filter array?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How to use `updateMany` first check if url  is present or not if present then update else insert. I  can use it in updateOne in filter I can add {url: "https://url.com"}
but when I am using updateMany how to check array of urls ["https://url1.com", "https://url2.com"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common way to update multiple documents each with its own data, is to use a bulk update with `upsert`

An example using js is:

```
const urlDataBulk = urlDataModel.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
for (const oneUrlData of urlsDataArr)) {
  urlDataBulk.find({url: oneUrlData.url}).upsert().update({$set:{company: oneUrlData.company}});
}
urlDataBulk.execute()
```